# How to run script shell before building on Jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins, build, integration-testing

(Jenkins newb-newb-newbie here)
Hi there.
I have a Maven project, deployed on Jenkins . In this project, I have an integration test, which depends on a .Net server in order to be run correctly.

The problem is, when I'm trying to build my project on Jenkins, the integration test fails, because the .Net isn't launched...

I need to execute a shell script (for launhing the .Net server) before building my project.
So my question is : how can I launch a script of my project before building from Jenkins?

Comment: how are integration tests performed locally? the server is manually started first? how do you normally start this server (via command line?)?

Comment: locally, I have first to launch my .Net server before running integration tests. I am compiling my server using 

     mcs src/*.cs -pkg:wcf -out:server.exe 

and then for launching my server, I'm doing 

    mono server.exe. 

I realized that there are "pre-build" options in the configuration of my job on Jenkins :) so I tried to run those lines before building.But now I have another problem : jenkins cannot find the commands mcs and mono...How can I add the right libraries (plugins?) in Jenkins?...tried to add the MSBuild plugin, but it didn't do much.

Comment: if the commands are part of the system path, Jenkins should find them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Theres a build step *Execute Windows batch command* which you could use to start your server.

You might have to use [START](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36343706/3623345) to have it launched in a separate process, so your build continues without waiting for the server process to finish, and you might need to put in some [delay](https://serverfault.com/questions/432322/how-to-sleep-in-a-batch-file) in case your server needs some time to settle before your tests can run.

You might also need to kill your server after your tests are done, you might be able to use `tasklist`and `taskkill` in another *Execute Windows batch command* build step, and some batch magic to do this.