# How to start a Window exe file in a Jenkins job

Tags: python, windows, jenkins

I have a Jenkins job in which I need to start windows program.
I've tried to use subprocess of Python to start the program, but it looks like when my python exits, the program also exits.  It somehow makes sense because it's a sub process...  Then I tried to start it like this `cmd c:\myprogram.exe` in Jenkins job, it still does not work....

Any advice?

Comment: What do you expect as a result. Do you want to start the program and keep it running? What kind of program is that? Is it sort of service? If it is supposed to be running after the jenkins job is over, who will stop the program?

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use [START](http://ss64.com/nt/start.html) to launch the program into a *separate* process.

Try `START c:\myprogram.exe`

Check following bash for a test.

> `@echo off
>   echo "launching notepad.exe"
>   notepad.exe
>   echo "Marker 1"
>   pause
>   echo "launching notepad.exe with START"
>   START notepad.exe
>   echo "Marker 2"
>   pause`

Comment: I want to start explorer.exe after is locks my workspace and your command doesn't work